# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but the elements print fine

Tags: java, regex, split

What is the meaning of this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Program.main(Program.java:123)

Here is line 123:

```
System.out.println(tempHolder[1]);
```

So it's saying there's no array element 1? However, this is in a loop, and all 100 elements in that position printed fine. Here's the code:

The array `splitResult` has 100 elements.

```
    int counter = 0;
    for (String s: splitResult){ 
      counter++; 
      counterForRegex = String.valueOf(counter);  
      stringRegex = "(\\s*)?" + counterForRegex + "(\\s*)?"; 
      patternCounter = Pattern.compile(stringRegex); 
      tempHolder = patternCounter.split(s, 2);  // This takes each of the 100 elements and separates it into 0) before the number, and 1) after the number, putting each element in array tempHolder.
      splitResult[counter-1] = tempHolder[0]; 
      System.out.println(tempHolder[1]); // These all print fine.
    }
```

Comment: Do proper debug on your code.

Comment: Print out the size of splitResult to verify it has 100 elements and also the size of tempHolder for each iteration and see if is always >= 2.

Comment: One of the strings in splitResult does not contain a sequence of digits; thus tempHolder.length == 1 and tempHolder[0] contains all of that string.

Comment: Maybe you should test first `if (!s.matches(".*" + stringRegex + ".*")) // will not split`

Answer (score 0):

`tempHolder = patternCounter.split(s, 2);`//When the number is not found and split results in returning just the input.

tempHolder.length will be 1 ,I this case java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown while trying to access tempHolder[1].

```
 tempHolder = patternCounter.split(s, 2); 
  if(tempHolder.length>=2){//check the length of tempHolder
     splitResult[counter-1] = tempHolder[0]; 
     System.out.println(tempHolder[1]); // These all print fine.
  }
```